# How are macros in C different from pre-defined data types in terms of storage?

Tags: c, macros

How are the values associated with a and b? How are values of a and b assigned to variables (when they are of different data types)

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define a 1
#define b 1

int main(void)
{   
   printf("%s", (a & b) ? "T":"F"); 
   return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not stored, they are replaced when they appear in the code by the preprocessor. So the code is "*literally*" equivalent to

```
printf("%s", (1 & 1) ? "T" : "F");
```